# Genuino 101 Serial.print not work in setup function

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I tried debug code in setup function.
but not output in setup function.
loop functions print is working collect.
My environment is Arduino IDE 1.6.13 and mac os.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup");
  Serial.flush();
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println("loop");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For native USB Arduinos like your Genuino, you should wait until the Serial port is open.

Just put a `while(!Serial);` right after your `Serial.begin(9600);`.

The Arduino Reference also has a [page about if(Serial)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/IfSerial).